# Does the currency sign (¤) go before, or after the amount?

Tags: numbers, symbols, measuring-units, money

Should the [currency sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)) (¤) come before, or after the amount of money?

Should it be "¤ 1.00", or "1.00 ¤"?

Should there be a space between ¤ and the amount?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)

Comment: @user121863 I know. I've already read that article three or four times over the course of several years.

Comment: @HotLicks The whole point of using the currency sign instead of a specific currency sign is that the currency in question is an *unspecified currency*.

Comment: I think it’s purpose is not to represent an *unspecified* currency, but rather to represent a currency symbol that is unavailable.

Comment: In Canada the $ goes before the number in English speaking provinces, and after it in French speaking ones, and I believe that in some countries the symbol goes between the whole number and the decimal part.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "... in some countries the symbol goes between the whole number and the decimal part" Could you give an example?

Comment: Why would one be writing about a specific numeric currency value when the actual currency is unknown or not specified? The reader can't tell what the specified number is actually worth if currency is unknown.

Comment: @nnnnnn There are many cases where the currency is unknown and there is no need to know the "true worth" of the amount. For example, when writing some answers to questions on https://money.stackexchange.com. Sometimes the currency is unknown (e.g. on old questions written by people who have left the site), and the "true worth" of the amount is irrelevant when making examples.

Comment: @Flux In France, mixed amounts of francs and centimes were often written as e.g. 3F50 and this has carried on with the Euro. [3F50 Air stamp](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/FRANCE-1936-3f50-BROWN-AIR-STAMP-USED-SG-539-CAT-32-/193710999358) - _L'abonnement Forfait est un tarif qui comprend un coupon valable 1 mois et vous devez réglez 1€50 de réservations par trajets en TGV_ (SNCF) _Soupe courgettes basilic 4€50 le litre Carottes 1€ le kilo Poireaux 1€50 le kilo_  (Grocery web site)

Answer (score 3):

Because it is a generic currency sign, it depends on what currency and in what country it is being used in. For example, in euros, it would be €23 or ¤23 but in american cents, it would be 10¢ or 10¤.

As to whether there is a space in between the symbol and the number, I would think that there probably wouldn't be as in most major currencies there is no space between the symbol and the number.

Comment: Agree. To my understanding it is purely typographical and is used to replace a currency sign that is unavailable. Thus it should be formatted as if the original symbol were being used.